# Debug C# dll from C++ solution via COM

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, com, .net-2.0

I have a C++ solution. The startup project is an exe. In the solution there are a number C# dlls (targeting .NET Framework 2.0) that are registered for COM interop. When I put a breakpoint in the C# code I get the hollow red breakpoint with `"No native symbols in symbol file"`

I have tried setting `Project Property Pages -> Debugging -> Debugger Type` to Mixed on the start-up project that calls the COM methods.

I have checked `Debug -> Windows -> Modules`. It has loaded my dlls, and the symbol status is `"No native symbols in symbol file"`.

This is not the end of the world because if I do `Debug -> Start Without Debugging` and then `Debug -> Attach to Process`, changing the `Attach To:` to `Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) code, Native code`. Then I hit breakpoints in both the C++ code and C# code.

So I have my workaround but I reckon if I can do it by attaching to process - I should be able to do it by just debugging.

How can I hit my C# breakpoints by just doing `Debug -> Start Debugging`?

Comment: Doubt that there is a feasible way, I tried the same, and spent hours trying to do that and finally got stuck with using the attach to process which works fine.

Comment: Fair enough, I have no issue with using attach to process it, is just one of those things where you can't leave it because you think "surely there must be a way"

Comment: I have this problem too and I guess the fundamental issue is that "Mixed" selects Native + Managed (v4.0), so there's no way to select Native + Managed (v2.0) from the startup settings.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to debug my C# dll from a C++ project in VS2008 by doing the following:

In the C++ project's properties, goto Configuration Properties -> Debugging. Set "Debugger Type" to Mixed. "Attach" should be set to No.

In your C# project properties, in the Debug tab, set the "Start External Program" to your C++ project's executable.

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit old but I found a practical solution for the problem.

I had the same problem while using a C++ application which uses a C# COM-Object. I tried several settings within Visual Studio on the C++ and C# side. Nothing helps until I tried manually launching the Debugger.

You can use

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

to manually start the Debugger on your C# DLL. I know this is not the best but a practical way. In later productive environments you have to remove the Debugger launch function :).

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if this will help but we work a lot with C# and C++. I found this to be possible by placing the C++ project and the C# project in the same solution and enabling "native debugging" in the C# project. Then I was able to jump back and forth between them while debugging.

Comment: I have both projects in the same solution and in VS2010 I have set the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" on all the C# projects. It still does not work. I am assuming that as the startup project is a C++ exe that the debugger is set to native only despite me setting the Debugger Type to Mixed in the C++ project properties.